# Maven auto-clean on package

Tags: eclipse, maven, initialization, package, m2eclipse

I'm having some troubles trying to auto-clean each time i run mvn package.
I've added in the POM :

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>auto-clean</id>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>clean</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        ...
    </plugins>
    ...
</build>
```

But i'm getting the following error from M2Eclipse :

> Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (execution: auto-clean, phase: initialize)

I've tried other phases like "validate" or "generate-resources" but i'm always getting the same error.

Comment: Just use **mvn clean package** ? What's the problem?

Comment: Just a idea: Maybe maven can't download the plugin (firewall, proxy)?

Comment: You may want to try replacing m2e's embedded Maven with a standard Maven install:  `Window` > `Preferences` > `Maven` > `Installations` > `Uncheck Embedded` > Add... `External` (path to where you installed Maven)

Comment: @khmarbaise There is a maven install on project clean that's configured. The point was to auomatically install the lib on package or on clean.

Comment: @Timo Was my first check but everything is there.

Comment: @Daniel The error is thrown by eclipse before even launching mvn package so that would not change the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a Maven problem, it's m2eclipse. I haven't used it in a long time, but apparently when you add some plugin executions, you have to add additional configuration to m2eclipse. There's a lengthy [description of this error on the Eclipse wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered).

Comment: new url: https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-execution-not-covered.html